# OpemXML - Read last node in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, openxml, sql-server-openxml

I have a XML like this

```
<Cat>
    <Inner>
        <PATCat>
            <Pat>SUR</Pat>
            <EfDa>20170411093000</EfDa>
        </PATCat>
        <PATCat>
            <Pat>MH</Pat>
            <EfDa>20170411094100</EfDa>
        </PATCat>
        <PATCat>
            <Pat>NRO</Pat>
            <EfDa>20170411095300</EfDa>
        </PATCat>
        <PATCat>
            <Pat>DAY</Pat>
            <EfDa>20170411110900</EfDa>
        </PATCat>
    </Inner>
</Cat>
```

and I am using the Query to read the nodes Pat and EfDa

```
SELECT      @PATCat_Pat = Pat,      
                    @PATCat_EfDa = EfDa,        

        FROM    OPENXML(@idoc, '/Cat/Inner', 2)
        WITH    (
            FiCl VARCHAR(20) 'PATCat/Pat',
            EfDa VARCHAR(20) 'PATCat/EfDa', 
            )
```

The result is @PATCat_Pat = SUR and @PATCat_EfDa = 20170411093000, Whereas I want to read the last node which is "DAY" and "20170411110900"

How can I achieve this? any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to add `last()` : `FiCl VARCHAR(20) 'PATCat[last()]/Pat',`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**value()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) and [**last()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/context-functions-last-xquery) for xml type instead of `OPENXML`

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<Cat>
   <Inner>
      <PATCat>
         <Pat>SUR</Pat>
         <EfDa>20170411093000</EfDa>
      </PATCat>
      <PATCat>
         <Pat>MH</Pat>
         <EfDa>20170411094100</EfDa>
      </PATCat>
      <PATCat>
         <Pat>NRO</Pat>
         <EfDa>20170411095300</EfDa>
      </PATCat>
      <PATCat>
         <Pat>DAY</Pat>
         <EfDa>20170411110900</EfDa>
      </PATCat>
   </Inner>
</Cat>'

SELECT @xml.value('(Cat/Inner/PATCat[last()]/Pat)[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS PAT,
   @xml.value('(Cat/Inner/PATCat[last()]/EfDa)[1]', 'varchar(30)') AS EfDa
```

Return

```
PAT     EfDa <br/>
DAY     20170411110900
```

Comment: Thank you TriV, the thing is I don't have an actual xml in the function, I only have a handle to the xml, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[last()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/context-functions-last-xquery) can be used with OPENXML as well.

```sql
SELECT Pat,      
       EfDa        
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/Cat/Inner/PATCat[last()]', 2)
WITH (
     Pat VARCHAR(20) 'Pat',
     EfDa VARCHAR(20) 'EfDa'
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

`FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

From a comment I get, that your function gets the handle, so you'll have to stick with this...

In your question you write, that you want to *read the last node which is "DAY" and "20170411110900"*.
What is your criterion? **last** or **the one with `<Pat>="DAY"`** or - if there might be more of the same - **the last of all `<PATCat>`, which has `<Pat>="DAY"`**? Are the elements always in the same order? Is the last `<PATCat>` always the one with `<PAT>="DAY"`?

You have got the solution with `last()` already. It will find the last `<PATCat>` no matter what's inside:

```
'/Cat/Inner/PATCat[last()]'
```

Looking for the one with "DAY" would be this

```
'/Cat/Inner/PATCat[(PAT/text())[1]="DAY"][1]'
```

If there might be more with "DAY" you could replace the last `[1]` with `[last()]`